# pagination-error in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I can't see what I'm doing wrong in my code.
I want to get the pagination-links to work but the result I get is the 404-error, The page not found...

This is my model:

```
class Clientlist extends CI_Model{
public function __construct()
{
        // Call the CI_Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
}

//Get full clients 
public function full_list($limit) {
    $sql = $this->db->get('clients', $limit);

    return $sql; 
}
public function count_list() {
    return $this->db->count_all('clients');
}
```

}

This is my view:

```
foreach ($client_list->result() as $cl) {
    echo $cl->fName . ' ' . $cl->lName . ' ' . $cl->cName . ' ' . $cl->cNumber . ' ' . $cl->phone . ' ' . $cl->mail .'<br />';
}
    echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

This is my controller:

```
$this->load->library('pagination');
                    $this->load->model('customers/clientlist');


                    $config['base_url'] = base_url('index.php/customers/cList');
                    $config['total_rows'] = $this->clientlist->count_list();
                    $config['per_page'] = 10;
                    $config['uri_segment'] = 3;

                    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
                    $results = $this->clientlist->full_list($config["per_page"]);


                    //Load the template.
                    $user_details = $this->login->user_details($id);
                    $view_info = array('username' => $user, 'details' => $user_details);
                    $header_info = array( 'title' => 'Registrera ny kund');
                    $this->load->view('template', array(
                        'view'          => 'customers/clist', 
                        'view_info'     => $view_info, 
                        'header_info'   => $header_info, 
                        'footer_info'   => '', 
                        'client_list'   => $results,
                        ));
```

Can you help me out and find what I have done wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: try to change your base url to an absolute path as such: `$config['base_url'] = base_url().'index.php/customers/cList';`

Comment: What do the generated links look like in view source?

Comment: @coderodour: No, thats not the right solution. Hmm. Wonder what went wrong here.

Comment: @ourmandave: Nothing that helps me out. I've already checked that output. But hey, thanks anyway!

Comment: what about changing the url segment to 2? the issue lies within your url/url construction on part of codeigniter. I am almost certain as I have had similar issues because of url configs.

Comment: @coderodour - No, that didn't work either :(

Comment: Check this out https://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/ you also may need to configure some routes in config/routes.php

Comment: Why would you expect paginated results when there is no limit and offset?